# how can i set alert dialogs into if and else statement

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have 2 `EditText`s that get a `String` and when the `Button` is clicked it converts `char` of this `String` to `int`. It then sums all `int` of `chars` and when sum of `int` is odd `(totals&1 == 0)` a `Dialog` shows "that is odd". And after `else,` the  second `Dialog` shows "that is even". I need to set `AlertDialog` to show that.

```
final EditText ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtFather);
        final EditText ed2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtMother);
        //final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtfather);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                String dataF = ed1.getText().toString();
                char[] charArray = dataF.toCharArray();
                int totalF = 0;
                for (char ch: charArray) {
                    totalF += characterMap.get(ch);
                }

                String dataM = ed2.getText().toString();
                char[] charArr = dataM.toCharArray();
                int totalM = 0;
                for (char ch2: charArr) {
                    totalM += characterMap.get(ch2);
                }

                int sum = totalF + totalM;
                int totals = sum % 5;
                if ((totals & 1) == 0)

                    //alert dialog 1 show "that is odd"

                else {

                    //alert dialog 2 show "that is even"

                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: You didn't even attempt to code an `AlertDialog`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### i found that i use AlertDialog like this :

> ```
>  btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>
>             @Override
>             public void onClick(View arg0) {
>                 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(StartActivity.this);
>                 builder.setMessage("that is odd");
>                 builder.setCancelable(true);
>                 AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
>
>                 String dataF = ed1.getText().toString();
>                 char[] charArray = dataF.toCharArray();
>                 int totalF = 0;
>                 for (char ch: charArray) {
>                     totalF += characterMap.get(ch);
>                 }
>
>                 String dataM = ed2.getText().toString();
>                 char[] charArr = dataM.toCharArray();
>                 int totalM = 0;
>                 for (char ch2: charArr) {
>                     totalM += characterMap.get(ch2);
>                 }
>
>                 int sum = totalF + totalM;
>                 int totals = sum % 5;
>
>                 if ((totals & 1) == 0)
>
>                     alert.show();
>
>                 else {
>
>                     AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(StartActivity.this);
>                     builder1.setMessage("that is even");
>                     builder1.setCancelable(true);
>                     AlertDialog alert1 = builder1.create();
>                     alert1.show();
>
>                 }
>
>             }
>         });
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setMessage("that is odd");
builder.setCancelable(true);
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Just write "that is even" instead of "that is odd" for the second dialog.

Comment: u said that i use this after if and other set after else ? when i use this code eclipse don't accept that

Comment: eclipse say that : AlertDialog.Builder can not be resolved to a variable

Comment: @DEJAVUSG Declare it out of else/if statement. 
AlertDialog.builder builder;
and then use "builder" inside if/else

Answer (score 0):

Use Toast for this purpose, they are a lot easier and fast for a single message.

```
    Toast.makeText(this, "Your Message here", 
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: yes thanks i khnow that is easy way but i wanna to change Toast with AlertDialog

Comment: Then the answer you are searching was given by Fondesa ;)